# Type hinting numpy arrays and batches

Tags: arrays, numpy, mypy, python-typing, type-annotation

I'm trying to create a few array types for a scientific python project. So far, I have created generic types for 1D, 2D and ND numpy arrays:

```py
from typing import Any, Generic, Protocol, Tuple, TypeVar

import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import _DType, _GenericAlias

Vector = _GenericAlias(np.ndarray, (Tuple[int], _DType))
Matrix = _GenericAlias(np.ndarray, (Tuple[int, int], _DType))
Tensor = _GenericAlias(np.ndarray, (Tuple[int, ...], _DType))
```

The first issue is that mypy says that `Vector`, `Matrix` and `Tensor` are not valid types (e.g. when I try `myvar: Vector[int] = np.array([1, 2, 3])`)

The second issue is that I'd like to create a generic type `Batch` that I'd like to use like so: `Batch[Vector[complex]]` should be like `Matrix[complex]`, `Batch[Matrix[float]]` should be like `Tensor[float]` and `Batch[Tensor[int]` should be like `Tensor[int]`. I am not sure what I mean by "should be like" I guess I mean that mypy should not complain.

How to I get about this?

Comment: What versions are you using? (Python, mypy, numpy) Because I fail to even get past your imports from `numpy.typing`. And do you think it is wise to import objects that have been explicitly made protected (leading underscore)?

Comment: python 3.9.13, numpy 1.22.4, mypy 0.812

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be using protected members (names starting with an underscore) from the outside. They are typically marked this way to indicated implementation details that may change in the future, which is exactly what happened here between versions of `numpy`. For example in `1.24` your import line `from numpy.typing` fails at runtime because the members you try to import are no longer there.

---

There is no need to use internal alias constructors because [`numpy.ndarray`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.22.4/numpy/__init__.pyi#L1486) is already generic in terms of the array *shape* and its *dtype*. You can construct your own type aliases fairly easily. You just need to ensure you parameterize the *dtype* correctly. Here is a working example:

```py
from typing import Tuple, TypeVar

import numpy as np


T = TypeVar("T", bound=np.generic, covariant=True)

Vector = np.ndarray[Tuple[int], np.dtype[T]]
Matrix = np.ndarray[Tuple[int, int], np.dtype[T]]
Tensor = np.ndarray[Tuple[int, ...], np.dtype[T]]
```

Usage:

```py
def f(v: Vector[np.complex64]) -> None:
    print(v[0])


def g(m: Matrix[np.float_]) -> None:
    print(m[0])


def h(t: Tensor[np.int32]) -> None:
    print(t.reshape((1, 4)))


f(np.array([0j+1]))  # prints (1+0j)
g(np.array([[3.14, 0.], [1., -1.]]))  # prints [3.14 0.  ]
h(np.array([[3.14, 0.], [1., -1.]]))  # prints [[ 3.14  0.    1.   -1.  ]]
```

The issue currently is that [shapes have almost no typing support](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16544), but work is underway to implement that using the new [`TypeVarTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVarTuple) capabilities provided by [PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/). Until then, there is little practical use in discriminating the types by shape.

---

The batch issue should be a separate question. Try and ask one question at a time.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! Is there any way to use the builtin types (e.g. `Vector[float]`)?

Comment: I'm afraid not. The numpy scalar types are different. The type must always inherit from `np.generic`. You may initialize arrays with iterables of regular Python types like `int` and `float`, but "inside" they will be turned into numpy specific types. And since you want to annotate numpy arrays, the correct type argument will have to be one of those scalar types.